# How to load a classmap[ped] Composer class (packagist) in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, composer

I've installed and deployed `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` in my Magento 1.9 and I am trying to add and use mpdf/mpdf (composer packagist) in a controller.

This package contains a classmapped file

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "filters/",
      "fpdi.php",
      "fpdf_tpl.php",
      "fpdi_pdf_parser.php",
      "pdf_context.php"
    ]
  },
```

Which is called in another component.

```
$this->parsers[$fn] = new fpdi_pdf_parser($fn);
```

And then Magento gives me the error

> Warning: include(Fpdi/Pdf/Parser.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory  in
>   /../mymagento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

The Mage.php seems to be patched properly, and I also tried to do `composer dumpautoload`.

**Some facts and findings**:

- If I create a `/newfile.php` (on the root folder, with not triggering Magento), include `autoload.php`, and call the method, it works.
- If I disable developer mode it works (and the warning is logged).
- If I change the Varien/Autoload.php and add an `if(stream_resolve_include_path($classFile))` (as suggested [here](https://www.webguys.de/magento-1/tuerchen-11-the-magento-autoloader-and-external-libraries)) before returning the include, it works (but I would override a core file).
- It seems that when composer autoload resolves `fpdi_pdf_parser` it makes a `require_once` to '`pdf_parser.php`' and at this stage Mage autoload is triggered instead of Composer's autoload.

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In which folder that FPDI install?

Comment: its under vendor/setasign/fpdi/fpdi_pdf_parser.php and the file that calls it, is vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php

Comment: you want to use that as web, not for cron, right?

Comment: Yes, for web and maybe cron

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain that the vendor directory is being autoloaded?  That's what that error sounds like - I had a similar issue and used this module (instead of modifying the Mage.php file, which could cause conflicts in future patches):

https://github.com/romantomchak/magento-composer-autoload

Comment: I tried to make changes in the Autoloader as well, but it was still breaking. Your changes works fine. The only change I would suggest in your autoload is at line 195... Magento uses include_once, instead of include. ;) Thanks for helping.

Comment: In fact I was precipitated, hehe. The problem continues even with your autoloader. I can't instantiate a new \Mpdf\Mpdf, which raises the same error (Warning: include(Fpdi/Pdf/Parser.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /Users/martins/www/magenteiro/app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php on line 181).
I tried to create a model that extends this, but unloads Magento autoload (spl_autoload_unregister([Varien_Autoload::instance(), 'autoload']);).
The problem is that anything that requires something from magento, after my Model is instantiated doesnt work.